# How does DisplayFormat attribute work?

Tags: c#, attributes, formatting

I am wanting to custom format a value by using a custom attribute so when I call `ToString()` my attribute properties will be used to format it.

When `int.ToString()` is called the `DisplayFormat` attrbiute (if defined) is used to format it.

But how does this work? Where does it work?

If I create a class like below

```
public class WeatherSingle
{
   private Single value;

   public override string ToString()
   {
      return "-> " + value.toString();
   }
}
```

And then use an attribute on the instance of the class how can my `ToString()` method get access to the attribute properties? The attribute is not defined on my class but the instance of the class in another class.

so say I have created a `WeatherAttribute` that takes a description and a couple of other properties and use it in another class like below

```
public class MyRecord
{
    [WeatherAttribute(description = "The current temperature in Celsius", format = "0.0", suffix = "Degree")]
    public WeatherSingle Temperature { get; set; }
}
```

If I call `MyRecord.Temperature.ToString()` it will trigger my overridden `ToString()` method but that method does not know about the attribute that I put on the property in the `MyRecord` class.

From the `MyRecord` class I can see my attribute, but that requires me to code it for that class and any class that I use the attribute in.

So how does `DisplayFormatAttribute` work for any property in any class?

How can I code my own attribute formatter which behaves like the `DisplayFormatAttriute`?

Comment: By the object type.  int, float, string all have an object type.  When you create a class that is also assign a 'type'.  So the ToString() method gets the object type and uses your custom format.

Comment: This does not answer the question how of it works, or how to write my own.  The real question is how is the attribute being linked to the to string method? most attributes are defined on a class and in that class you do something but display format seems to work on any class.